# VBA Automation/Monitoring/Development

Tags: excel, automation, monitoring, analysis, vba

I am working as coordinator of EUCs at my department (more than 50 people and more than 150 MS Excel macros for controls and reporting). In order to keep good track of Macros usage and measuring tool performance, I have added a simple code to each workbook that collects usage data (who and when had opened/closed workbook, how much it takes for a macro to perform certain tasks, etc...). The code is pretty simple, it collects all data in a public variable and before the close of the workbook, it saves the content of a variable to a .txt file in a folder.

```
Option Explicit

Dim info_data as String

Sub check_point(x as integer)
Select x
 Case 0
 Call WBK_close
 Case 1
 Call WBK_open
 Case 2
 Call WBK_main_start
 Case 3
 Call WBK_main_end
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub WBK_close()
 info_data = info_data & "WBK Close;" & Now()
 Open myFile For Output As #1
 Print #1, info_data
 Close #1
End Sub

Private Sub WBK_open()
 info_data = "WBK Open;" & Now() & vbNewLine
End Sub

Private Sub WBK_main_start()
 info_data = "WBK Main Start;" & Now() & vbNewLine
End Sub

Private Sub WBK_main_end()
 info_data = "WBK Main End;" & Now() & vbNewLine
End Sub
```

I am using a check_point sub at a certain point in the code to make a record.

Sometimes there happen some errors, especially when other macros also writing something to text files. Or when purely written code exit `Sub` with use of `End` statement, erasing all data saved to `info_data`.
Therefore, I am wondering if there is a smarter way to collect MS Excel usage data (other codes, add-in, use of another programming language, alternative ways of data storing (not txt)).

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but maybe you could try to trigger your code with the events `Workbook_Open` and `Workbook_Close`?. That way you make sure you won't conflict with other subs, but the problem is that sometimes a macro is done but if the workbook is still opened, you won't be able to catch the real end-time.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thanks for advise. This is exactly what I am doing :). It is successfully collects data about macro with the use of the checkpoints at the beginning and at the end of Main Sub. The question more about efficiency and troubleshouting. I also would be glad to see any other solutions to this case, if somebody have similar experience :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the problem that they have multiple workbooks open at once each with a macro running? And Each of those macros is trying to write to the text file?  If that's the case then write to a database (SQL Server of a network located Access DB)? The DB gets rid of the multiple concurrent users issue and also means all your data is already in one place (as opposed to you periodically collecting text file from their computers).

If you write to a DB they of course need to be on your domain. Maybe that is not always possible. But maybe those circumstances in which they are not on the domain it is acceptable to lose the tracking. Alternatively, you could write to a dedicated text file in those circumstances then once domain connectivity is restored, write whatever info you need from there to your DB.

Comment: We are working on share drives, hence there no problem with collection of text files, from my perspective. Regarding the DB, would it have impact on performance (As I understand it would be better way to store records rather then in thousand of separate files)? I mean  is there difference to write to text file or to DB. Any tutorials on that or more description? I would be very thankful

Comment: @Lincoln if the goal is to aggregate user data how do thousands of text files help? If you're writing to a DB on a network I'd think it would be just as fast and you only need to manage one file/table. Working through all those files sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: thank you for comment, I am currently testing database structure. Seems to be a way better solution. Currently having some problems with consistency of records, It happens so that some of the records contain "WBK Open" message and missing the "WBK Close" line.

Comment: Would it be better to prepare an add-in rather than a use of VBA?

Comment: @Lincoln When you debug the close event is there something about it that's failing? Is there error handling in the event? I think an Add-in would work as well however it sounds like your macro enabled workbooks are widely distributed. By keeping the Code contained in VBA you're able to have full functionality to anyone who opens that file. If you use an Add-in then you'll be limited to logging info from only those users who have installed the add-in. Seems like it could be a hurdle for many users.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure Application Insights to track usage, performance, error tracking for your VBA projects (Excel & Access) in real-time, online.
It uses a little tool called VBA Telemetry.
If you don't have a Microsoft Azure account you can create and use a free one.
A few days ago I create a Udemy course on how to do all that. 
It is a quick, short course (30 minutes) and in first 24h there were 2400+ people enrolled.
You can watch a preview of this course to see if this is for you.
The link to this course:
[VBA Application & Usage Monitoring Online with Azure cloud-Udemy course](https://www.vbatelemetry.com/U1STEX10209)
Hope this helps,
Davor

Comment: Thanks @davor.geci. It seems to be very worthy. Will take a look definitely :)

Comment: No problem, if you will have any question, we can talk there in Q&A